# How to attach file to email template?

Tags: c#, smtp

I've never been working with email until today.
I have to attach to email some file  to email template.
This is code how I'm sending the information.
Attachments is logo of template comes from appsettings.

```
public async Task SendSingleEmail(SmtpEmailData emailData, byte[] csv = null)
        {
            var recipients = emailData.RecipientEmailAddress.Count > 1
                                 ? emailData.RecipientEmailAddress.Aggregate((x, y) => this.MaskEmailAddress(x) + ", " + this.MaskEmailAddress(y))
                                 : this.MaskEmailAddress(emailData.RecipientEmailAddress.FirstOrDefault());

            var loggingInfo = new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Sender", emailData.SenderEmailAddress),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Recipients", recipients),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Subject", this.MaskSubject(emailData.Subject)),
            };

            try
            {
                var mailMsg = new MailMessage();

                emailData.RecipientEmailAddress.ForEach(recipientEmail => mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipientEmail)));

                mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(emailData.SenderEmailAddress);

                mailMsg.Subject = emailData.Subject;

                var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(emailData.Content, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

                emailData.Attachments.ForEach(
                    attach =>
                        {
                            var attachment =
                                new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(attach.Content), new ContentType(attach.Type)) { ContentId = attach.ContentId };

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attach.Name))
                            {
                                attachment.ContentType.Name = attach.Name;
                            }

                            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(attachment);
                        });

                mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView); 

                if (emailData.Calendar != null)
                {
                    var contype = new ContentType(CalendarContentType);
                    contype.Parameters.Add("method", emailData.Calendar.Method);
                    var calendarView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(emailData.Calendar.Content, contype);
                    mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(calendarView);
                }

                // Init SmtpClient and send
                var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(this.smtpConfig.ServerAddress, Convert.ToInt32(this.smtpConfig.ServerPort));
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.smtpConfig.UserName, this.smtpConfig.Password);
                smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMsg);

                this.logger.LogInfo(EmailSent, loggingInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(ex, FailedEmailSending, loggingInfo);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Need now somehow to attach the file. How should i make it to attach?

Comment: Attachments and linked resources are not the same thing. If you want to attach a file then read the documentation for the `MailMessage` class, which you should already have done. It includes a code example that creates an attachment.